# How do I convert 'Apr9,20037:33am' to a unix timestamp?

Tags: php

I have a date in this format: `Apr9,20037:33am`

How do I turn into a timestamp?

Comment: If you search for "php string to timestamp" in Google (or on the PHP.net website) it comes right up in the top two results on both.

Comment: When I type "string to timestamp" in the search box on http://php.net/ I get a dozen matches -- #2 is strtotime()

Comment: PHP manual time functions overview: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Umm, first off, that break there at the end with kill your foreach loop after the first item.

Comment: I know, I just want to get the first conversion done. I put that there for debug.

Comment: Well, without spaces in it your own solution is to use `substr` to parse out each piece of it. Then you can implode the pieces with a space and use `strtotime` if you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

`$unix_timestamp = strtotime('Apr 9, 2002 11:33 am')`

EDIT: Asker changed question, above no longer applies.

Comment: Really? I should be penalized b/c the asker edited the premise of the question? At the very least you should have edited my answer to say it no longer applies.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a format that can't be parsed also take a look at: [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)

Comment: Pentium10: Your seeming reluctance to put any personal effort into this is annoying. There are examples _on that page_ on what you can do if you are using a previous version of PHP. Please do some legwork yourself.

Comment: Doesn't work out. If I make echo `date2sql('Apr9,20027:33am');` I get really weird value: 943956000

Comment: What's this `date2sql` function you're talking about?

Comment: it's the method for older php versions for `date_parse_from_format`, linked on the PHP page

Comment: And why are you using it? (I'm not aware of this function... never heard about it) What php verion are you using?
If you just used it because there is nearly the same example than yours on the php site, then please take care take you used it correctly...

Comment: It's on the linked page you mentioned. Scroll down on that page.

Comment: Did you pay any attention to it, or did you just try to use it? It's for a specific date format, which isn't your format. Use your brain.